# Scenario 47: Replacing Dead Head With Body Token?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Just got done playing my first full game with three of my other friends. My buddy who introduced us to the game became the traitor, and we had a blast. However, the fate of the Heroes is in the hands of this very rule!

As stated in the rules for the Ouroboros, their body stays in each room it moves through. However, when one of the heads is defeated, is it replaced with a body token? Otherwise, does the head stay in the room dead and impeding the movement of the Heroes (assuming the head takes up the majority of the room causing a bit of trouble for traveling)?

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but it's worth noting that stunned enemies do not slow your movement.

Comment: According to the rules, the Ouroborus cannot be stunned. Thanks for the point, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You do not replace the Ouroboros head with a body token

During a Haunt, special actions are explicitly given in the following books:

- [Secrets of Survival](https://web.archive.org/web/20191120072131/http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_SurvivalRev_120105.pdf) (read by the Heroes)
- [Traitor's Tome](https://web.archive.org/web/20191120072132/https://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_TraitorRev_120105.pdf) (read by the Traitor)

According to the Traitor's Tome, the Ouroboros head only leaves behind a body token on movement, and only if there isn't already a body token in the room it just left. Since neither the Traitor's Tome nor the Secrets of Survival state that anything happens when an Ouroboros head is killed (outside of the Survivors winning if both are killed), it is not replaced with a body token on death.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, is the head still kept on the map? Does it impede movement for the Heroes?

Comment: Stunned monsters in general cannot impede movement for the Heroes. While the base rules don't seem to explicitly state this, it's implied that dead characters (hero, traitor, or monster) cannot impede movement either. I would assume that a dead character's token/piece is removed from the board when they die, but I can't see where specifically in the rules this is stated. If someone else can point to where this is stated, by all means do so (or edit the answer to include this information).

Comment: This seems reasonable. I’ve marked your answer as the final answer. Thank you for your help.